# Timer between two keyevents

Tags: java, android, service, timer, keyevent

I would like to create an application with two keyevents, volume as well as power buttons, my application flow is like this,

When i press volume button my timer will get start and within 30 seconds of timing when i press power button  it should give me a toast in activity as well as service is it possible ?

Sample code I used in activity :

```html
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
 {
      super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      long startTime=0;
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
      {
   long mills = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
     int seconds = (int) (mills / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds/60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        if((seconds>=3 && seconds<=30))
        {
          System.out.println(seconds);
          System.out.println("Timer Working");
          System.out.println("App Working");
          if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
          {
           Toast.makeText(this, "It's Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           event.startTracking();
           return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is actually problem? Also probably this will be hard to achieve because when you press power button, screnn is truned off, so showing toast have no sense. If toast is just your example, then you're maybe also interested in detecting ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Thread and a Handler to manage this.